# Use of "best intentions"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Scenario: There is a manager in a shop who works his very best to make sure the shop does well (financially). He cares for the shop as if he is the owner.

Can I convey this using the following sentence?

> The shop has a manager, who, with his best intentions, runs the place.

Comment: I would use "effort" or "endeavor".

Comment: Idiomatically *with **the** best [of] intentions* normally comes *after* the relevant verb phrase, and is usually only used in contexts where even those best intentions *fail* to to achieve whatever was intended.

Comment: I think that "with single-minded devotion" does a better job of indicating the quality of the manager's approach that you are trying to convey.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really, because "with his best intentions, runs the place." can imply that, *despite* his best intentions, the place was a mess.

You could consider "The shop has a manager, who runs it so well it's as if he's the owner."

Answer (score 1):

"With the best of intentions" is always followed by **"but."**

So most UK English speakers would e understand you to be saying, "This person tries very hard, and means well, but never manages to get it right."

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_road_to_hell_is_paved_with_good_intentions) shows that the phrase has been picked up by Byron, Kierkegaard etc etc etc.

Comment: That last one is reassuring.

Comment: @Ricky Alas! marked [citation needed] I should have listed Karl Marx and Samuel Johnson.

Comment: I'm afraid your first sentence isn't even approximately true.  [See COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=43192837).